# Mock Instant.now() without using Clock into Constructor or without Clock Object

Tags: java, junit, java-8

I have below code in one of my methods

```
ZonedDateTime current = Instant.now().atZone(ZoneId.of(AMERICA_NEW_YORK));
```

I want to mock `current` in the JUnit test.

I tried with `java.time.Clock` but for this, I need to add it into the class constructor as my code is written into old versions of Spring and using XML based configuration this class cause issue because it requires constructor argument in the application-context.xml file if I use a constructor with `Clock`.

Is there any way to avoid constructor configuration and mock `current` in the above code.

**Update**

As per Pavel Smirnov's comments, I tried below but `current` still returning today's date but not the one which I am mocking.

```
ZonedDateTime exactOneDay = ZonedDateTime.parse("Sun Oct 21 12:30:00 EDT  2018", Parser); 
doReturn(exactOneDay).when(spyEmployeeHelper).getCurrentTime();
employee = getEmployees().get(0);
assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(1), employee.getNoticePeriod());
```

Comment: You can try to use PowerMockito and mockStatic for Instant.now()

Comment: Best way would be refactoring your method to extract this line into a new method. Then you can easily mock/spy that method.

Comment: The best way to go is to change the constructor and update the `application-context.xml` accordingly.

Comment: it's funny that your title mentions `mock`, but no mocking frameworks have been mentioned in your question

Answer (score 13):

Mockito based solution where code uses plain `Instant.now()`

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.MockedStatic;

import java.time.Clock;
import java.time.Instant;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mockStatic;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.spy;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

public class MockInstantTest {

  private MockedStatic<Clock> clockMock;

  @BeforeEach
  public void setup() {
    mockInstant(1640000000); // set desired return value 2021-12-20T11:33:20Z
  }

  @AfterEach
  public void destroy() {
    clockMock.close();
  }

  private void mockInstant(long expected) {
    Clock spyClock = spy(Clock.systemDefaultZone);
    clockMock = mockStatic(Clock.class);
    clockMock.when(Clock::systemDefaultZone).thenReturn(spyClock);
    when(spyClock.instant()).thenReturn(Instant.ofEpochSecond(expected));
  }

  @Test
  void testWithMockedIstant() {
    // invoking Instant.now() will always return the same value
    assertThat(Instant.now().toString()).isEqualTo("2021-12-20T11:33:20Z");
  }
}
```

**Solution Explained**

The implementation of `LocalDateTime` looks like this:

```java
public static LocalDateTime now() {
   return now(Clock.systemDefaultZone());
}

public static LocalDateTime now(Clock clock) {
   Objects.requireNonNull(clock, "clock");
   final Instant now = clock.instant();  // called once
   ZoneOffset offset = clock.getZone().getRules().getOffset(now);
   return ofEpochSecond(now.getEpochSecond(), now.getNano(), offset);
}
```

- Works with Java 21
- We need an instance of `Clock` (I recommend `Clock.systemUTC()`, so we don't have to worry about time-zones) for spying
- `clock.instant()` is mocked to return the desired value
- `Clock.systemDefaultZone()` is static so we need mockStatic
- using `@Before`/`@After` is required to close MockedStatic (alternatively you can use `try(MockedStatic<Clock> clockMock = mockStatic(Clock.class)) {...}`)

Comment: Be sure to include artifact _mockito-inline_ (instead of just _mockito-core_).

Comment: Does not work with JDK 17 (Eclipse Temurin 17.0.2.8) anymore. Worked with JDK 11 though.

Comment: `Instant.now()` returns `null`; therefore, user871611 is correct to indicate that this might not be working with Java 17 any longer.

Comment: I get it to work in Java 21. I updated the answer.

Comment: Didn't work on Java 8

Answer (score 5):

You can declare a function that returns `ZoneDateTime`:

```
public ZoneDateTime getCurrentTime () {
    return Instant.now().atZone(ZoneId.of(AMERICA_NEW_YORK));
}
```

and assign the result of that funciton to the `current` field:

```
ZonedDateTime current = getCurrentTime();
```

Now you can simply replace it with desired value using [Mockito framework](https://site.mockito.org/):

```
doReturn(yourValue).when(yourObject).getCurrentTime();
```

Comment: Thanks Pavel. I am trying same way but `current` still returning today's date and not what I expected. Please see my updated question.

Comment: @ppb, The piece of code that you have provided looks fine. Can you show the full code of you test? How do you create spyEmployeeHelper?

Comment: I am crating spyEmployeeHelper by `EmployeeHelper spyEmployeeHelper = mock(EmployeeHelper.class);` this way. I also tried `EmployeeHelper spyEmployeeHelper = spy(employeeHelperObject);` by this way.

Comment: assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(1), employee.getNoticePeriod()); Should not you invoke getNoticePeriod() method on your spy object, instead of 'employee'? Check in your debugger what instance is 'employee' object of?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution that works with Java 17, leveraging Mockito's static mocking and its `CALLS_REAL_METHODS` option to avoid mocking all of `Instant`'s static methods.

```java
var clock = Clock.fixed(Instant.now().minus(10, ChronoUnit.MINUTES), ZoneOffset.UTC);
ClockUtil.setClock(clock);
var mockedInstant = Instant.now(clock);
MockedStatic<Instant> mockedStatic = mockStatic(Instant.class, Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS);
mockedStatic.when(Instant::now).thenReturn(mockedInstant);
```

Answer (score 1):

When using Mockito you can easily mock like so:

```
    ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("America/New_York");
    ZonedDateTime current = ZonedDateTime.now(zoneId);
    Timestamp timestamp = Timestamp.from(Instant.now());
   
    when(timestamp.toInstant()).thenReturn(Instant.from(current));
```

Adding Test for timeout example:

```
@Test
public void testForTimeout() throws InterruptedException {

    ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("America/New_York");
    ZonedDateTime current = ZonedDateTime.now(zoneId);
    Timestamp timestampBeforeCall = Timestamp.from(Instant.now());

    // Call Class.method() or here instead we just introduce an artificial wait time :
    Thread.sleep(3000);

    Timestamp timestampAfterCall = Timestamp.from(Instant.now());
    long timeoutInMilliseconds = 2000;
    long diff = timestampAfterCall.getTime() - timestampBeforeCall.getTime();
    log.info(String.valueOf(diff));
    if(diff > timeoutInMilliseconds) {
        log.error("Call Timed Out!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Really nice! Can you show how you would use it to test a class that e.g. uses Instance.now() in one of its functions (e.g. to find if there is a timeout)?