# How can i stub Instant object using powermock

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermockito

Is there a possibility to stub Instant object using Powermock?
Powermock has the capability to mock final/static classes/methods.

I wanted something like :

```
Instant instant = PowerMockito.mock(Instant.now().getClass());
when(instant.getEpochSecond()).thenReturn(76565766587L);
```

i would need this mocking to be used elsewhere within my service class where i insert into table giving the time of that instant.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: see [detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55289157/mock-instant-now-without-using-clock-into-constructor-or-without-clock-object/70186748#70186748) with code example on mocking Instant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is.

My dependencies:

```
     <dependency>
         <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
         <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
         <version>2.0.4</version>
         <scope>test</scope>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.28.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
```

And my JUnit:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Instant.class})
public class InstantTest {

    public InstantTest() {
    }

    private Instant mock;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Instant.class);
        mock = PowerMockito.mock(Instant.class);
        PowerMockito.when(Instant.now()).thenReturn(mock);
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Mockito.doReturn(76565766587L).when(mock).getEpochSecond();
        assertEquals(76565766587L, Instant.now().getEpochSecond());
    }
}
```

This code works, but IMHO insert into table is about Integration Test, not Unit Test so you need an embedded or testcontainers database and a roundtrip test where you really write data and read it again.

Comment: The following dependency is required.  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

Comment: You're right, I missed in copy and past from my pom. Added to solution

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import ru.apibank.delivery.service.publisher.runners.PowerMockTestRunner;

import java.time.Instant;

@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(PowerMockTestRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(value = {Instant.class})
public class TestClass {

    @Test
    public void testInstant() {
        long epochSeconds = 76565766587L;
        Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond(epochSeconds);

        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Instant.class);
        Mockito.when(Instant.now()).thenReturn(instant);

        Assert.assertEquals(epochSeconds, Instant.now().getEpochSecond());
    }
}
```

You also can use BDDMockito
`BDDMockito.given(Instant.now()).willReturn(instant);`

Comment: PowerMockTestRunner.class seems to be ur internal package.

Comment: Also this dosent work!! even if i use PowerMockRunner.class. Sorry!!

Comment: You should add dependency of PowerMock in your pom file

```<dependency>
                <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
                <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.0-beta.5</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
                <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.0-beta.5</version>
            </dependency>
```