# Unit test case failed: zero interactions with this mock

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

I have written a test case to test `StateMachineExecutorManager` class but it is throwing below errors:

> Wanted but not invoked:
>   com.amazon.heimdalltttingestionservicelambda.utils.StepFunctionUtility.startExecution(StepFunctionUtility.java:43)
>   Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

Unit test code:

```java
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class StateMachineExecutorTest extends BaseTester {

    private static final String EVENTS = "{\"Records\":[{\"eventVersion\":\"2.0\",\"eventSource\":\"aws:s3\",\"awsRegion\":\"us-east-1\",\"eventTime\":\"2018-11-02T14:02:43.283Z\",\"eventName\":\"ObjectCreated:Put\",\"userIdentity\":{\"principalId\":\"AWS:AIDAIMIQPLFXDFSTWXCGM\"},\"requestParameters\":{\"sourceIPAddress\":\"10.4.50.122\"},\"responseElements\":{\"x-amz-request-id\":\"7EEC615C11B5C373\",\"x-amz-id-2\":\"GCI+e/xr+vKZjnCy3IpUJIn9XrIEzDdiZOTBKXzsqgbwqFDlZ91gGKWj8d0W/UbUdqoWYCuf1lw=\"},\"s3\":{\"s3SchemaVersion\":\"1.0\",\"configurationId\":\"InboundManifestSQSNotify\",\"bucket\":{\"name\":\"test-bucket\",\"ownerIdentity\":{\"principalId\":\"A1JUPHJ1SEYN6S\"},\"arn\":\"arn:aws:s3:::ftpayroll-test\"},\"object\":{\"key\":\"inbound/lenel_badge/testfile.csv\",\"size\":4960,\"eTag\":\"df3a71421cc268356754c9069ca9d517\",\"sequencer\":\"005BDC59032AAAD3EE\"}}}]}\n" +
            " ";

    StateMachineExecutor stateMachineExecutor;
    StepFunctionUtility stepFunctionUtility;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        super.setup();
        this.stateMachineExecutor = new StateMachineExecutor(testServiceComponent.stateMachineExecutorManager());
        this.stepFunctionUtility = mock(StepFunctionUtility.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void testSuccess(){
        S3Event s3Event = getS3Event();
        try{
            stateMachineExecutor.handleRequest(s3Event, mockContext);
            verify(this.stepFunctionUtility, times(1)).startExecution(any(IngestionWorkflowMetadata.class));
        }catch(Exception exception){
           failTheTest();

        }
    }
    private S3Event getS3Event(){
        S3EventNotification s3EventNotification = S3EventNotification.parseJson(EVENTS);
        S3Event s3Event = new S3Event(s3EventNotification.getRecords());
        return s3Event;
    }
}
```

Class to test:

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
public class StateMachineExecutorManager{

    StepFunctionUtility stepFunctionUtility;

    public Void handleRequest(final S3Event s3Event) {

        final S3Entity s3Entity = S3Utility.getS3Entity(s3Event);
        IngestionWorkflowMetadata executionInputs = generateStepFunctionExecutionInput(s3Entity);

        Environment.log(String.format("Received trigger for - Bucket: %s, Key: %s",
                s3Entity.getBucket().getName(), s3Entity.getObject().getKey()));
        try{
            stepFunctionUtility.startExecution(executionInputs);
        }catch (JsonProcessingException jsonProcessingException){
            Environment.log(String.format("[%s]: Error in JSON Parsing", LogMetricKeys.JSON_PARSING_FAILED));
            throw new RuntimeException(jsonProcessingException);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private IngestionWorkflowMetadata generateStepFunctionExecutionInput(final S3Entity s3Entity){
        final IngestionWorkflowMetadata executionInput = new IngestionWorkflowMetadata();
        try{
            executionInput.setBucketName(s3Entity.getBucket().getName());
            // S3 keys use URL encoding, e.g. '=' becomes '%3D'
            executionInput.setFileKey(S3Utility.decodeS3Key(s3Entity));
            executionInput.setExecutionId(generateStepFunctionExecutionId());
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException unSupportedEncodingException){
            Environment.log("[%s]: Error in decoding S3 file key: [%s]",
                    LogMetricKeys.S3_FILE_KEY_DECODING_FAILURE_, s3Entity.getObject().getKey());
            throw new RuntimeException(unSupportedEncodingException);
        }
        return executionInput;
    }

    private String generateStepFunctionExecutionId() {

        final String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        return  String.format("%s_%s", uuid, Instant.now().toEpochMilli());
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you expect your `stepFunctionUtility` mock to be passed to `StateMachineExecutorManager`?

Comment: This is a singleton class and configuration has been done with the help of Dagger dependency framework

Comment: My point is: in the code you posted you don't pass `stepFunctionUtility` to it. If there is no code that does that and hasn't been posted, then you don't interact with the mock but some other object (`StateMachineExecutorManager` has all args constructor, but it is unclear how you call it in your test).

Comment: @RonySingh you probably can try annotating `stateMachineExecutor` in junit class with `@InjectMocks`.

Comment: see [detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55289157/mock-instant-now-without-using-clock-into-constructor-or-without-clock-object/70186748#70186748) with code example on mocking Instant