# Mocck issue with Instant.now().toString()

Tags: java, unit-testing, kotlin, timestamp, mockk

I have implemented an interface. There I am passing timestamp as parameter to a function. For geting the current time, I have used `Instant.now().toString()`.

The function looks like this:

```
fun createId() {
    val values = Record(name = "ABC", timestamp = Instant.now().toString())
    interface_name.store(values)
}


@Test
fun `test1 for createId`() {
    val values = Record(name = "ABC", timestamp = "2020-12-28")
    every { interface_name.store(values) } just runs
}
```

This is giving me: `Verification failed` because the timestamp is different. I am unable to figure out how do I mock the Instant.now() so that I get the static timestamp while testing. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Pass a `Clock` to `Instant#now(Clock)`. During testing you pass your own `Clock` and during normal operations you use the system-default `Clock`.

Comment: @Slaw can you elaborate? where do I pass the clock?

Comment: You must not use `Instant.now()` in your real code.  You must have your real code accept a `Clock` -- e.g. in your class's constructor -- and pass it to `Instant.now()`

Comment: see [detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55289157/mock-instant-now-without-using-clock-into-constructor-or-without-clock-object/70186748#70186748)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unit testing is easy when all the dependencies are passed as parameters. Hence instead of creating objects within the function, it is always good to design the function based on abstraction and pass the dependency as arguments.

```
fun createId(clock: Clock = Clock.systemUTC()): Record {
    val values = Record(name = "ABC", timestamp = Instant.now(clock).toString())
    interface_name.store(values)
    return values
}


@Test
fun `test1 for createId`() {
    val clock = Clock.fixed(Instant.parse("2021-01-01T00:00:00Z"), UTC)
    val record = createId(clock)
    assertEquals(Record(name = "ABC", timestamp = "2021-01-01T00:00:00Z"), record)
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help. I tried this, but mocking one confusion i have is, how do I mock the Clock.instant() call?

Comment: @PiyushDoke You don't want to mock the `Clock.instant()` call. You're already passing a "mock" `Clock` by using `Clock.fixed`.