# Static Utility Class, Unit Testing and Java.Time

Tags: java, unit-testing, time, static

Due to our client still using Java.Date.Util, we've had to deal with various converting methods and a large bloated Date Utility class. My goal is to simplify the Utility class and write unit tests for it.

I've managed to simplify it, but I'm running into issues with test cases because:

1. As an Utility class, the methods are static, thus no dependency
   injection using Java.Time.Clock.
2. Several of our helper methods use instant.now() before converting it to the format requested. Obviously this makes writing unit tests... problematic.

Here are some examples of the methods I need to write test cases for:

```
     /**
     * Get the current time in any format.
     * @param outFormat
     * @return
     */
    public static Object getNow(TimeFormat outFormat){
        Instant dateObject = Instant.now();
        
        return new InstantConverter().convertTo(dateObject, outFormat);

    }
    
    /**
     * @param value - unit of time 
     * @param unit  - hours, days, etc. Anything higher than days is not supported. 
     * @param format - format returned. 
     */
    public static Object calculateFutureDate(int value, ChronoUnit unit, TimeFormat outFormat) {
        Instant time = Instant.now().plus(value, unit);
        
        return new InstantConverter().convertTo(time, outFormat);
    }
```

**InstantConverter** is a protected class that converts Instant to various time outputs (localdate, string, epoch, java.util.date, etc) while **TimeFormat** is an enum that contains all the formats we can convert to.

I know it's best practice to move away from static methods when it comes to unit testing... but i'm afraid that is not an option.

In my research, it seems my only options are using powermock or one of the later versions of mockito to mock my static instant.now() method (similar to: https://rieckpil.de/mocking-static-methods-with-mockito-java-kotlin/).

I just want to make sure I'm not missing anything obvious as I don't want to refactor *again* as I made a mistake.

Thank you anyone who took the time to read this! Let me know if  you have any questions.

Comment: why do you make those methods static?

Comment: `Mockito::mockStatic` is what we use to test static utility methods, if that matters

Comment: Why do you need to write tests for those methods? They don't contain any of *your* logic, so at most you would test `InstanceConverter.convertTo()`.

Comment: The only method that needs to be static here is `Instant.now`, which can be injected to that utility class, if needed

Comment: @njzk2 This is a utility class. Tons of other classes, workflows and more call these methods. I've been told I cannot switch it to a non-static class where you have to instantiate this class. Requirements, alas.

Comment: @Kayaman client wishes for each method to have some tests. Most of the testing will be done with the InstanceConverter, but they do want basic test cases for the others.

Comment: @purpleglade that's not a requirement, that's a wish. If  `InstantConverter` doesn't need to be static, then whatever that class is doesn't need either (sorry, I realize this doesn't help much, but I really think that kind of requirement needs to be pushed back)

Comment: see [detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55289157/mock-instant-now-without-using-clock-into-constructor-or-without-clock-object/70186748#70186748) with code example on mocking Instant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing keeping you from injecting a `Clock` into a class containing static utility methods.

1. Declare a `private static Clock` field (a class variable). Initialize it to, say, `Clock.systemUTC()` or `Clock.systemDefaultZone()` in the declaration.
2. Have your static time-sensitive methods use the `Clock` just introduced.
3. Have a package private (default accessible) static `inject`or `setClock` method that injects a `Clock` into the static variable.
4. If desired, have an `uninject` method that sets the `Clock` back to its initial value.

Keep your unit tests in the same package so that they may use the package private inject method. As you may have figured out, a test method testing a static utility method first injects its desired `Clock`, then calls the method to test and validates the return value from the method. Since the `Clock` is static, tests cannot run in parallel.

Comment: This might be exactly what I needed, I'll test it now. I had a feeling I was missing something simple.