# how to verify void method in junit

Tags: java, junit, mocking, verify

Im pretty new with the tests. Just because it looks like Ive got issues with mock I decided to ask you guys for help. Can you tell how correctly tests for those methods should looks like, please? This is what ive got:

class for test:

```
public class EnhancedJwtCache extends TimerTask {
    ConcurrentHashMap<String, EJwt> cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    
    public void init() {
        
        new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(this, TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(1), TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(1));
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        log.debug("Checking enhanced token cache for expired entries.");

        // Remove any eJWT's from the cache that have expired.
        Iterator<String> iterator = cache.keySet().iterator();
        
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            String key = iterator.next();
            if (cache.get(key).isExpired()) {
                log.debug("Removing expired token from cache for user {}", cache.get(key).getUsername());
                iterator.remove();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and my test so far which returns me error because its not mock:

```
class EnhancedJwtCacheTest {

    ConcurrentHashMap<String, EJwtAuthenticationToken.EJwt> cache;

    @Mock
    EnhancedJwtCache underTest;

    EJwtAuthenticationToken.EJwt ejwt;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    void runTest(){

        List<String> roles= Arrays.asList("Roles1");
        ejwt = new EJwtAuthenticationToken.EJwt(
                "encodedJwt",
                Instant.now().plus(10, ChronoUnit.DAYS),
                "name",
                "username",
                roles
        );

        cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        cache.put("cache", ejwt);

        verify(underTest,times(1)).run();
```

Comment: see [detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55289157/mock-instant-now-without-using-clock-into-constructor-or-without-clock-object/70186748#70186748) with code example on mocking Instant

Answer (score 1):

You don’t want to mock the class that you’re testing in the test. Then you would be testing the mock, not the class.

To test a `void` method, it needs to have some observable side-effect that you can verify in the test. In this case, you’d want the test to add a mix of expired and non-expired entries to the cache, then call `run`, then check the list of cache entries again to be sure the expired ones are absent and the non-expired ones are present.